# How to disable excel suggestion of conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

On 2016, every time you select/copy/paste a range, there's a little icon at right-side lower corner of the selection, giving you some options.

If you use they keyboard extensively to navigate throughout Excel, you can unintentionally focus on these options using Ctrl.

I've already disabled the following

Excel Options > Advanced > Cut, copy, and paste > Show Paste Options button when content is pasted

Excel Options > Advanced > Cut, copy, and paste > Show Insert Options buttons

Now, there's one more button that suggests Conditional Formatting, and I want to disable that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File > Options > General > User Interface Options > Uncheck Show Quick Analysis options on selection

Comment: This is important because the idiotic and undesired "suggestion box" prevents Ctrl-V. Forgive the rather 'attaboy' but this answer should have 10,000 upvotes because I see people over and over and over scream about that "suggestion box" yet the answer above provides the solution that they all need to read ... since MS cluelessly only supplies the useless options/Advanced answers that the original question pointed out. It's maddeningly unintuitive so I want to emphasize the importance of this accurate and uberuseful answer.